# How to update color of a Swing Oval

Tags: java, swing

I would like to dynamically update the color of a Swing Oval I have drawn in my java swing app. Can Someone please help me?

my circle class I created to draw the ovals:

```
public static class Circle extends JPanel{
        int x;
        int y;
        int diameter;
        Color color;
        public Circle( int x, int y, int diameter, Color color ) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.diameter = diameter;
            this.color = color;
        }
        @Override
        public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
            super.paintComponent( g );
            setSize( diameter + 1, diameter + 1 );
            g.setColor( color );
            g.fillOval( x, y, diameter, diameter );
            
      }
    }
```

Where I add the circle to my panel (status circle is an instance variable in my class):

```
statusCircle = new Circle( 0, 0, 15, getStatusColor(currentSimStatus) );
statusCircle.setBackground( Color.DARK_GRAY );
bottomPanel.add( statusCircle );
```

Where I want to update my circle, **note** the setCurrentSimStatus is called externally by another class which should in turn trigger the update. This is working as the statusText JLabel value does update as expected. I'm just unsure of how to update the circle:

```
public void setCurrentSimStatus( String newStatus) {
        currentSimStatus = newStatus;
        this.update();
    }

private void update() {
        
        statusText.setText( "Current Sim Status:" + currentSimStatus );
        statusCircle = new Circle(0, 0, 15, getStatusColor(currentSimStatus) );
        statusCircle.updateUI();
        System.out.println("repainting");
    }
```

Comment: Don't modify the state of the component from within `paintComponent` (ie `setSize`).  Don't call `updateUI` - it doesn't do what you think.  With the same instance of `Circle` which is on the screen, change the `color` property and then call `repaint` on the instance

Comment: Instead of `setSize`, override `getPreferredSize`

Comment: *This is working as the statusText JLabel value does update as expected.* - well , how the text on the JLabel change? You invoke the setText(...) method of the label, you don't create a new JLabel. If you want to change the Color of the circle, then you need a method like `setColor(...)` that you invoke on the Circle object instead of creating a new Circle object.